# My UWP application freezes for several seconds when making database queries

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I have this code to retrive a single object from SQLite database, but when I select the listbox Item that use this code, the application freezes for a couple of seconds. I think I have to modify this code to async operation:

```
public FFSystems ReadFFSystem(int FFSystemID)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), App.DB_PATH))
    {
         var existingFFSystem = conn.Query<FFSystems>("select * from FFSystems where ID =" + FFSystemID).FirstOrDefault();
         return existingFFSystem;
    }
}
```

How can I modify this code?

Comment: Do not form your database queries by concatenating together strings, that opens you up to SQL Injection attacks. See [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) for an explanation of why this is a bad idea, and then the [C# example](http://bobby-tables.com/csharp) for how to fix it. You appear to be using Dapper, so this should be an easy fix. Also, it's generally not a good idea to use `select *` - that can pull more data than you need. Instead, explicitly select which columns you want.

Comment: Take a look at `Task.Run()` method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/keep-the-ui-thread-responsive

Comment: I wouldn't go straight to Task.Run, it is wasteful for I/O operations like database calls.

Comment: @mason Thanks, I'll take a look at those links :)

Comment: Check the documentation for `SQLiteConnection`. If it doesn't have an async version of `Query` you'll have to call the method in the background with `Task.Run`. That won't be truly asynchronous as it will use a thread to wait for a response but at least the UI won't freeze.

Comment: @Crowcoder SQLiteConnection doesn't have async methods. Understandable since SQLite is an embedded database that could even store data in-memory

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok, that's unfortunate.

Comment: @ZampTom [SQLiteAsyncConnection](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLiteAsync.cs) has asynchronous methods.

Comment: Thanks to all of you, I'll take a look to those documentation and I'll let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this nuget package: `SQLite.Net.Async-PCL` for your project.

Then you could refactor your code like this:

```
using SQLite.Net.Async;

    private SQLiteConnectionWithLock GetAsyncConnection()
    {
        var localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path;
        var path = Path.Combine(localFolder, FileName);
        var connString = new SQLiteConnectionString(path, true);
        var conn = new SQLiteConnectionWithLock(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), connString);
        return conn;
    }

    public async Task<FFSystems> ReadFFSystemAsync(int FFSystemID)
    {
        SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() => GetAsyncConnection());
        return await conn.Table<FFSystems>().Where(s => s.ID ==FFSystemID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    }
```

Then you can get the data like this:

```
var obj = await ReadFFSystemAsync(5);
```

Comment: Hi, mason, `SQLiteAsyncConnection` class does not implement `IDisposable`, so we cannot create its instance in `using( ){ }` manner, which is used in creating the instance of `SQLiteConnection`.

Comment: Furthermore, the only constructor of `SQLiteAsyncConnection` is `public SQLiteAsyncConnection([NotNull] Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock> sqliteConnectionFunc, [CanBeNull] TaskScheduler taskScheduler = null, TaskCreationOptions taskCreationOptions = TaskCreationOptions.None)`, so in my code, I put a lambda expression which type is `Func<SQLiteConnectionWithLock>` when initializing `SQLiteAsyncConnection`.

Comment: This Works so well! Thanks!